# free jqGrid with Caption and without column headers

Tags: jqgrid

I want to display the caption, but not the column headers.  When the grid is first displayed only the caption should be visible.  When the grid is expanded, the column headers are visible.  Please see [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/user20150603/7v70640y/)

```
var $grid = $("#grid");

$grid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view")
  .children("div.ui-jqgrid-hdiv")
  .hide();
```

Comment: did my solution helped you or you are looking for something else?

Comment: Thanks, however, this is removing the column headers from all the jqgrids I have on my page.  I tried to select the 'grid' element and use the 'find' method.  But, this did not work.  $grid.closest('div[role="columnheader"]').parent().hide();

Comment: Check the updated solution now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/7v70640y/5/

```js
$("#grid").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        { name: "firstName" },
        { name: "lastName" }
    ],
    caption: "The caption",
    hiddengrid: true, 
    data: [
        { id: 10, firstName: "Angela", lastName: "Merkel" },
        { id: 20, firstName: "Vladimir", lastName: "Putin" },
        { id: 30, firstName: "David", lastName: "Cameron" },
        { id: 40, firstName: "Barack", lastName: "Obama" },
        { id: 50, firstName: "François", lastName: "Hollande" }
    ]
});

$('div[role="columnheader"]').parent().hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<table id="grid"></table>
```

Just hide the `div` & it's parent `div` which has **role** as **columnheader**

`$('div[role="columnheader"]').parent().hide();`

**Update** with multiple `jqGrid`

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/7v70640y/6/

```js
$("#grid1").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        { name: "firstName" },
        { name: "lastName" }
    ],
    caption: "The caption",
    hiddengrid: true, 
    data: [
        { id: 10, firstName: "Angela", lastName: "Merkel" },
        { id: 20, firstName: "Vladimir", lastName: "Putin" },
        { id: 30, firstName: "David", lastName: "Cameron" },
        { id: 40, firstName: "Barack", lastName: "Obama" },
        { id: 50, firstName: "François", lastName: "Hollande" }
    ]
});

$("#grid2").jqGrid({
    colModel: [
        { name: "firstName" },
        { name: "lastName" }
    ],
    caption: "The caption",
    hiddengrid: true, 
    data: [
        { id: 10, firstName: "Angela", lastName: "Merkel" },
        { id: 20, firstName: "Vladimir", lastName: "Putin" },
        { id: 30, firstName: "David", lastName: "Cameron" },
        { id: 40, firstName: "Barack", lastName: "Obama" },
        { id: 50, firstName: "François", lastName: "Hollande" }
    ]
});


$('#gview_grid1').find('div[role="columnheader"]').parent().hide();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/css/ui.jqgrid.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/free-jqgrid/4.14.1/jquery.jqgrid.min.js"></script>
<table id="grid1"></table>
<br/><br/>
<table id="grid2"></table>
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: He don't wan't hide column header when he collapse the caption.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted.  Thanks!